# Query retornando resultado não desejado

Tags: sql, sql-server

Na minha instrução sql:

```
SELECT DISTINCT C.TABLE_NAME,C.CONSTRAINT_NAME,C.COLUMN_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE C
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS T 
ON T.TABLE_NAME = C.TABLE_NAME
WHERE C.TABLE_NAME = 'VALOR_CAMPO_DATA' 
AND C.COLUMN_NAME IN ('ID','REV') 
AND T.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'FOREIGN KEY';
```

Gostaria que retornasse somente FK's, porém está vindo também PK's. eu especifiquei no `where T.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'FOREIGN KEY'`, mas não está funcionando, se eu executar somente o `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS` funciona,

Alguém sabe como eu resolvo este problema?

Comment: [Veja se esse link ajuda](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Se você quer FK's porque não fazer um `select` em `sys.foreign_keys`ou ainda usar a proc `EXEC sp_fkeys 'nome-da-tabela'`?

Comment: Faltou adicionar o seguinte no inner join:

    AND T.CONSTRAINT_NAME = C.CONSTRAINT_NAME

Caso contrário ele irá duplicar informações pois o TABLE_NAME consta tanto para PK quanto para FK, portanto traz ambos

Comment: @AndréLuan publique sua resposta lá que funcionou...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Faltou adicionar o seguinte no inner join:

```
AND T.CONSTRAINT_NAME = C.CONSTRAINT_NAME
```

Caso contrário ele irá duplicar informações pois o TABLE_NAME consta tanto para PK quanto para FK, portanto traz ambos

Comment: Show, muito obrigado.